# Remix Getting VM error: invalid opcode

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, dapps

[image]after I deployed the contract,and execute `setData` or `getData`, the status section shows

```
message:transaction to SimpleData.setData errored: VM error : invalid opcode,invalid opcode.
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract SimpleStorage{
    uint myData;
    
    function setData(uint newData) public payable{
        assert(newData >1);
        myData = newData;
    }
    
    function getData() public view returns(uint){
        return myData;
    }
}
```

My compiler verision is 0.5.12.
plz help me, i'm beginner.

Comment: even if i delete "assert(newData >1);", the error shows again

Comment: what is the opcode that is invalid? debug.traceTransaction() and it will show up at the last line, add this to your question so we can understand.

Comment: There were new opcodes added to the EVM from 2015, so if you are using interpreter of 2015 with a bytecode compiled for Constantinople for example, there will be no SAR (bit shift rotating) instructions for example, so the EVM will produce "invalid opcode" error

Comment: @bbjoker That's an old remix version I suggest using the newer interface at remix.ethereum.org.